# Graph visualisation in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, tree, graph, prefuse

I have a data structure that represents a directed graph and I'm looking for a good Silverlight visualisation to allow me to navigate from node to node, preferably with some nice animation.

Does anyone know of any good UI controls or frameworks for this kind of display? Even a sample from another field (maybe a social network?). My graphs don't have many nodes so performance won't be an issue.

I've seen the [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/gallery/) library for Java (and Flash) which would be ideal. The "Degree of Interest" visualisation is the kind of thing I'm after, but I can't find anything in Silverlight.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open source option that's part of the Silverlight Bag-O-Tricks. Check it out and see a demo here (use the first demo link):

http://www.codeplex.com/BagOTricks

There's also a WPF version:

http://j832.com/bagotricks/

Comment: Thanks Jared, this doesn't offer quite as much eye candy as the prefuse libraries but it's the best I've seen so far for SL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one
http://graphlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I made a graph library for Silverlight, that uses Dot as basis.
Please check out: http://dot2silverlight.codeplex.com/

I am making some improvements to support more shapes and types of arrows.

daniela

Answer (score 0):

Must admit I haven't tryed it out yet my self but [quickgraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph) looks promissing

Answer (score 0):

@Rune FS

QuickGraph has no visualisation capabilities, at least not for Silverlight. It just handles the graph data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

QuickGraph does make it easy to construct a graph and output to Directed Graph Markup Language (DGML) which can be viewed in VS 2010.  I just checked in changes to the project and I noticed that it has been designed to be built for inclusion into Silverlight.  So perhaps you could use it in conjunction with a silverlight DGML viewer